# Proxy or something else to mirror website?

Tags: proxy, squid, mirror

I want to set up a website on my internal network that mirrors the bbc iplayer website and have all the associated functionality.

The internal site will be a vm or a container with a vpn client inside that gets around the geographical restrictions that the iplayer site has; I've go this part figured out and working.

I assume I need a forwarding proxy ? but is there anyway I can just set something up so that when I go to http://iplayer.local the player site is mirrored there and then that site uses the vpn client to contact the bbc ?

I don’t want to have to put any configuration into my browser to force clients to use the proxy.

Thanks,

Comment: Just to be clear, what exactly do you mean by "mirror"? Usually the term "mirror" implies an exact copy of the original, but in the strictest sense, that's not possible in most cases using plain web access. The term also usually implies that if the original goes down or becomes unavailable, then the mirror remains available with unchanged functionality; that implies that *all* material available on the mirrored site is copied to the mirror. Is that really what you are trying to do? Or do you simply want internal clients to be able to access the site through another name?

Comment: As a license-fee paying Brit, this sounds dodgy.

Comment: I want the site to be accessible via another name but have that site proxy to the iplayer ... least I think thats what I want to do.

Comment: Steve not dodgy I pay a licence too. I just spend maybe a 3rd of the year out of the UK.